# the role of div in creating jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, html, append

I'm trying to create a grid of circles which change color when clicked. The code I currently have to create the grid visually (which works) is this:

```
var color = null;
for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++) { // row
    for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) { // column
        var myCircle = document.createElement('div');
        myCircle.id = "circle";

        myCircle.style.left = r * 56 + "px";
        myCircle.style.top = c * 56 + "px";

        document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(myCircle); //maybe error
    }
}
```

I want to turn this into its jquery equivalent to handle the change in state on clicking. Here's what I've got so far:
var color = null;

```
for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++) { // row
    for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) { // column

        var $myCircle = $("#circle");
        $myCircle.style.left = r * 56 + "px";
        $myCircle.style.top = c * 56 + "px";
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $($myCircle).click(function() {
         $($myCircle).css('backgroundColor', 'color');
               });
         });
        $('#grid').append($mycircle);
    }
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Do I need to introduce the 'div' somewhere in the above code? How?

Answer (score 2):

you are selecting an element and not creating here

```
$("#circle");
```

try this

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++) { // row
      for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) { // column
         var $myCircle = $("<div />").attr({class:"circle"}).css({left:r * 56 + "px" ,top :c * 56 + "px"}));  //creating a div element with its attributes...
         $('#grid').append($mycircle); //appending it to grid
      }
     }

      $('#grid').on('click','#circle',function() { //using on delegate for dynamically added  div
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'color'); 
       });
     });
```

for click event to work for dynamically added element, we need to delegate it to closest static parent. **and ID should always be unique so its better to change your ID to class which i am doing here.**

**updated**

updated some errors in your fiddle check it out..

remove the  . in mycircle

```
 var $myCircle = $('<div />').addClass('circle').css({
                        //-------------^---removed the `.`..
```

and changed all you javascript to jquery..

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/yhb9A/55/)

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same ID on a page :)

Comment: Hi! I tried using this but it didn't work. I'm not sure what the error is. I've changed my circle from an ID to a class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is my css code for circle:
 .circle {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#FAEBD7;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

Comment: I have not created a div in my CSS. do i need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myCircle = $("#circle");
```

Should be:

```
var myCircle = $("#circle")[0];
```

Because you use the DOM native functions, but it's a jQuery wrapper.

Note that I removed the `$` prefix from `myCircle` because now it's a DOM element.

Comment: Alternatively, you could show how the OP could actually use the much more convenient jQuery collection methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing a bunch of appends like this, it performs better to use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment). The code would look like this:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++) { // row
    for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) { // column
        var $circle = $('<div/>').addClass('circle').css({left: r*56, top: c*56});
        frag.appendChild($circle.get(0));
    }
}
$('#grid').append(frag).on('click', '.circle', function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});
```

But I suggest going with an inline-block approach to layout your circles. The [Compass mix-in](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/inline_block/) is really handy for this. Also, the [border-radius Compass mix-in](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/border_radius/). This way, your code is reduce to:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    frag.appendChild($('<div/>').addClass('circle').get(0));

$('#grid').append(frag).on('click', '.circle', function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});
```

Also, you don't need to specify + 'px' on jQuery css props. Don't forget the `/` before the `>` in `$('<div/>')` either. I created a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jedhunsaker/44wEp/5/) with the last solution.

And here's the supporting SCSS:

```
$radius: 50px;
$gap: 6px;

#grid {
    width: ($radius + $gap) * 5;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-radius: $radius;
    width: $radius;
    height: $radius;
    border: $gap/2 solid white;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Even better, have the click do a `toggleClass('active')` and set the CSS `.active {color: red; }`